# how to return the pointer of a specific value in a tree in C?

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, tree, function-definition

using this struct :

```
typedef struct node {
  int content;
  struct node* right;
  struct node* left;
}Node;
```

I'm trying to write a code that return the pointer of the the node if node ->content== x
I have tried this so far but I don't think its right :

```
 Node* find (Node* p,int x)
{
  Node* L,*R;
    if(p==NULL)
    retutn NULL;
  L=find(p->left,x);
    if(L->content == x)
    return L;
  R=find(p->right,x);
    if(R->content == x)
  return R;
}
```

can u help me correct my code?

Comment: This declaration: `Node* L,R;` declares the variable `L` of type 'pointer to `Node`' and the variable `R` of type '`Node`'. I'm afraid it's not what you intend....

Comment: It will only examine one node with it's immediate children. You need to rather perform recursive search on each subtree.

Comment: Could you, please, describe, what this instruction does: `L=(p->left,x);` ...?

Comment: `p->left,x` looks fishy. Read about the comma operator, it does not do what you think it does. BTW does this compile??

Comment: @CiaPan it just means to go left

Comment: Sorry, there is too much wrong and missing here. You should study from a textbook and/or turn to your teacher or teaching assistant for help, or possibly fellow students. As another comment nodes, `Node* L, R;` does not declare `R` to be a pointer. `L=(p->left,x);` indicates flounding, just throwing code at something hoping it will work, like some kind of crude pattern matching in ignorance of what the symbols mean. To assign `L` to point to the place that `p->left` points, we simply use `L = p->left;`. `(p->left,x)` does not represent the structure.

Comment: Also `Node* L,R;` does not what you thinkt it does. It's the equivalent of `Node* L; Node R;`. You probably want `Node *L; Node *R`, or `Node *L,*R;`

Comment: Further, to search a tree for a specific value, we either need to search the entire tree or we need some organizing principle that tells us which parts of the tree to search. E.g., if the tree is organized using the value of `content` as a key, with all nodes having a `content` value less than the current node on the “left” side of the night and those with a greater value on the “right” side. If it has an organizing principle like that, we can easily choose which direction to search next, and a simple loop suffices to search. If it does not, we have to search both sides of every node.

Comment: @EricPostpischil ...my fault I meant L=find(p->left,x);

Comment: @nina you should also [edit] your code and correct it _there_

Comment: No. That's a vague description of _what you want_ it to mean. But I ask, what operations should the code perform while executing that instruction. Code does not know things like 'go left'. It can read the value of a variable, store the value to some other variable, it can do some arithmetics or comparisons on values... It can read or write a component (member) of some compostite variable... What do you expect your code will do within that line of your program? `L=(p->left,x);`

Comment: and yes we dont have specific order so we have to search all the nodes @EricPostpischil

Comment: `L=find(p->left,x);`: `find` may return NULL, therefore `if (L->content == x)` right after will be a problem...

Comment: Please let your code through some compiler and read error and warning messages it will print. What you present here is not even a valid C program due to errors—and StackOverflow is not an online debugger. If you have problems with code structure or data structure, many peple here will be happy to help you, but don't expect someone will teach you the language from scratch.

Comment: You fixed some erros, alas you introduced new one. Suppose `find(p->left,x)` did not find the value `x` in the `left` subtree – what happens in the following conditional `if(L->content == x) ...` then?

Answer (score 0):

First, the code doesn't even compile because of `retutn`.

---

```c
L=(p->left,x);    // Equivalent to: L = x;
```

should be

```c
L=find(p->left,x);
```

Same idea for the right side.

---

`L` could be NULL.

```c
if(L->content == x)
```

should be

```c
if(L != NULL)
```

or just

```c
if(L)
```

Same idea for the right side.

---

You never check if the current node is a match. You need to add the following:

```c
if ( p->content == x )
   return p;
```

---

The following is correct:

```c
Node* L, *R;
```

However, it's very easy to accidentally do

```c
Node* L, R;
```

Maybe you should avoid grouping such declarations. On the plus side, this should be caught at compile-time (unless you avoid turning on even the most basic warnings).

---

All together,

```c
Node* find(Node* p, int x)
{
   if ( !p )
      return NULL;

   if ( p->content == x )
      return p;

   Node* L = find( p->left, x );
   if ( L )
      return L;

   Node* R = find( p->right, x );
   if ( R )
      return R;

   return NULL;
}
```

Comment: 4 returns in maybe 10 lines. Multi return code is difficult to read and more error prone then function is longer

Comment: 0___________, Quite the opposite in my mind. Deep nesting is far worse. Harder to read and adds to the mental context.

Comment: sorrry 5 returns :)

Comment: The last four lines can be replaced with `return find(p->right, x);`, but the uniformity adds to the readability.

Answer (score 0):

The part of the function starting from these statements

```
L=find(p->left,x);
  if(L->content == x)
  return L;
```

is incorrect. For starters it is unclear why the node pointed to by the pointer p is not checked. And the call of the function can return a null pointer. So this if statement can invoke undefined behavior.

The function definition depends on whether it is a binary search tree or not. That is whether nodes of the tree are ordered.

If it is not a binary search tree then the function can be defined the following way

```
Node * find( const Node *root, int x )
{
    if ( root == NULL )
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else if ( root->content == x )
    {
        return ( Node * )root;
    }
    else
    {
        Node *p = find( root->left, x );
        return p == NULL ? find( root->right, x ) : p;
    }
}
```

If the tree is a binary search tree then the function can look the following way

```
Node * find( const Node *root, int x )
{
    if ( root == NULL )
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else if ( x < root->content )
    {
        return find( root->left, x );
    }
    else if ( root->content < x )
    {
        return find( root->right, x );
    }
    else
    {
        return ( Node * )root;
    }
}
```

A non-recursive function can look the following way

```
Node * find( const Node *root, int x )
{
    int found = 0;

    while ( !found && root != NULL )
    {
        if ( x < root->content )
        {
            root = root->left;
        }
        else if ( root->content < x )
        { 
            root = root->right;
        }
        else
        {
            found = 1;
        }
    }

    return ( Node * ) ( found ? root : NULL );
}
```

Comment: If it is BST you can use `while(root) {...}` instead of recursion. :)

Comment: This line: `p == NULL ? return find( root->right, x ) : p;`  should not even compile...

Comment: @CiaPan It was a typo. As for your first comment then the author tries to write a recursive function.

Comment: Yes. But they never said the recursion is _required_. In fact, it is useful if we may need to scan the whole tree (and do not want to use an explicit stack or queue). However, if we know we're dealing with a BST, the search goes conditionally along a single simple path down to leaves, so the recursion is too much; it adds much stack house-keeping and return-value handling with no gain in efficiency and a little gain in code legibility.

Comment: Possibly the shortest, but still clear iterative code: `while (root != NULL) { if (root->content == x) return root; if (root->content < x) root = root->left; else root = root->right;} return NULL;` (alas, no newlines in comments). Simply: found? then return the answer. Else test and proceed to the left or to the right. Not found? then return NULL. Done.

Comment: @CiaPan This approach will not work for floating point numbers. The operator == can return false.

Comment: Not just _can_. If you compare different values, it even _should_ return false.

Comment: @CiaPan For floating point numbers there is such a notion as precision. Two floating numbers can be no less or greater than other but they are not equal. But from the program point of view they should be equal.

Comment: Could you, please, give an example of two f.p. values (not NaN of any kind, nor ±Inf) which satisfy none of `>`, `<` or `==`? A hexadecimal dump of IEEE 754 representation will be OK.

Comment: @CiaPan For example a difference can be in the last digit of the internal representation of mantissa. but from the mathematical point of view they can be equal because in the mathematics there is no restriction on presentation of floating point numbers. The same initial values of type double and of the type float in the same operation can yield different values. Instead of the operator == you should use the operator <. In C++ all ordered data structures are based on this operator.

Comment: I did not ask about problems of precision, quantization, truncation and rounding, which arise when we try to cast the mathematical continuum of real numbers into the world of finite-constant-length computer representation and perform calculations in it. You said comparison with `==` **will not work for floating point numbers**, because **it can return false.** So please show, for what values, none of which is `<` or `>` than the other one, the operator `==` returns false.

Comment: @CiaPan  Numbers that can be represented are not uniformly spaced; the difference between two consecutive representable numbers varies with the chosen scale.

Comment: @CiaPan Or see here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/CompareOfFloatsByEqualityOperator.html

Comment: I see there is no point to wait for an answer. Thank you for the talk. EOT.